# Gradle plugin for eclipse luna updates classpath on every run

Tags: plugins, gradle, classpath, eclipse-luna, eclipse-classpath

Recently i switched to eclipse luna along with gradle plugin for luna. But eclipse updates classpath for  all my gradle prohects each time I launch eclipse. It may be a needed feature but is there a way to disable it? Or is it even normal for eclipse to do so?
I didnt face this issue with eclipse juno.
Thank you in advance